# why __len__() give different output result for s = [] and s=[[]]?

Tags: python, list

code snippet:

```
>>>s = []
>>>len(s)
0
```

however:

```
>>>s = [[]]
>>>len(s)
1
```

I just declare two lists but did not assign any element, why `len()` give different output?

Comment: The second `s` has a reference to an element

Comment: Er, because the first list is empty, but the second list contains something?

Comment: Also, there is no reason ever to call `.__len__()`, or any of the double-underscore methods, directly. Always call the built-in function: `len(s)`.

Comment: I just start to learn python, I still thing in the way of C++ stl, I tried to call some function, my auto completion prompt this function, so I use this, anyway, I learned a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` is an empty list, it has zero elements.
`[[]]` is a list with exactly one element, an empty list.

```
>>> for x in []:
...     print(x)
... 
>>> for x in [[]]:
...     print(x)
... 
[]
```

As your can see, the first for loop prints nothing, because there's nothing in `[]`. The second for loop prints `[]`, because there's `[]` inside `[[]]`.

If you know the concept of sets from math, here's an analogy:
Let x = {} be the empty set. Then the set {x} contains one element (the empty set).

Answer (score 5):

You *did* assign an element. Your second list contains *another empty list*:

```
>>> l = [[]]
>>> l
[[]]
>>> len(l)
1
>>> l[0]
[]
>>> len(l[0])
0
```

If it helps, break down what you did into two steps; create an empty list then create another list with just that one element:

```
>>> l1 = []  # empty
>>> len(l1)
0
>>> l2 = [l1]  # one element
>>> l2
[[]]
>>> len(l2)
1
```

Other than that we have one more reference to the nested list, the outcome is exactly the same; an empty list contained within another list object.

You could add any number of empty lists inside an outer list; that doesn't make the outer list empty however:

```
>>> len([[], [], []])
3
```

because each of those empty lists contained in the outer list is still a separate object.

Note: use the `len()` built-in function, don't call the `__len__` method directly. Python takes care of that detail for you.

If you wanted to know the total lengths of all contained lists, you could use:

```
sum(len(sub) for sub in outer)
```

or you could use:

```
not any(outer)
```

if you just wanted to know if all contained elements are 'empty' or otherwise considered false.

Demo:

```
>>> s = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]  # not empty
>>> not any(s)
False
>>> sum(len(sub) for sub in s)
4
>>> s = [[], []]  # all empty
>>> not any(s)
True
>>> sum(len(sub) for sub in s)
0
```

Comment: so how could I get a two dimensional list s, if I call len(s), the output is 0?

Comment: @DongweiWang: what is your goal here, what problem are you trying to solve? Do you want to test if all *elements in the list* are empty? Then use `not any(some_list)`; that'll return `True` if *all* the elements in the list are [considered false](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). So `[[], 0, False, '']` would qualify, as would `[[]]`.

Comment: I want to declare a two dimension array s, and the output of len(s) is 0

Comment: @DongweiWang: you can't. The outer list is *not empty*. `not any(s)` would be `True` if the contained lists are empty though.

Answer (score 4):

In one case you do have an element in your list : an empty list.

```
s = [[], []]
```

has two elements for example.

```
s = [[]]
```

has one element and

```
s = []
```

is empty

Answer (score 2):

The second list indeed contains an element, which is an empty list.